# Excel 2016: Work sheet, subtraction of time

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, date-time

I am working on a work sheet. Sometimes I work late and sometimes long hours (outside the 24 hour time frame).

I am looking for a automated solution in Excel where I can easily calculate the total number of worked hours with those the scenario below.

Note: I have formatted the result cell in: [h]:mm format.

started working: 23:05

stopped working: 01:35

Total number of hours worked: 02:00

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Which numbers are you trying to subtract from which?  What have you tried and what was the result or error?

Comment: How do you get 26:25 from the first example? If you may be working longer than 24 hours I think you need to include the date in both start and end time, then you can just subtract one from the other for worked hours

Comment: @Alexander Are you only expecting the complete hours worked? as the example you show (23.05 and 01.35) is 2.5 hours... Anyway, Barry has given you the solution...

Comment: Was not as easy as someone claimed it to be. I solved it w/ a conditional statement.

Comment: Would you like to give your solution as an answer - it may help others with similar puzzles?

Comment: If the result you want is 2:00, there are some missing rules about rounding and partial hours.  The question isn't answerable without clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

### Assume

- You are working on some time sheet, which each working period is not longer than 24 hours.
- A1 stores start working time (without date part, say `23:05`).
- B1 stores stop working time (without date part, say `01:35`).

---

### Answer

Input the formula into C1, then format it as `[h]:mm`.

```
= B1 - A1 + IF(B1 < A1, 1, 0)
```

You will get the duration of the working time in C1, say `2:30` (2hr 30mins).

---

### Explanation

Normally, `B1 - A1` is the duration between start & stop working time.

But, if `B1 < A1`, it means that the worker worked pass midnight, we need to add `1` (day) to the result.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work : format the cells as date and time, or only time and take the difference.

Unlike another answer posted this give a duration of 2hrs 30 mins which should be correct...

Here is an image showing it working :
[image]

You can also format as time and it still works:
[image]

Comment: What if his sheet contains only time information, but not dates?

Answer (score 0):

Since my previous solution was not calculating correct result. In fact was not including 55 Minutes, so that I'm posting this one.

Now using the Data which are Cell **A2 is  20/11/2017 23:05** & **in Cell B2 is 21/11/2017 01:35**, the following formula will count the correct difference of the Time.

D2 = (B2-A2).

And the **trick is Format the Result  Cell like [hh]:mm**.

**Answer will 2:30Hrs ,will count the  Date difference also.**

Answer (score -1):

For better result I would like to suggest you to do the followings,

1. Format both the Cells for DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS.
2. Format the Formula Cell as HH:MM:SS.

Suppose in **Cell A2** Start Date & Time is 20/11/2017 23:05 and in **B2** End Date & Time is 21/11/2017 01:35.

Write the **Formula in D2** ,

=TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),SECOND(B2)-TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2)))

**The answer I got is 01:34:59**.

**NB:** To make the combination with your suggest Time, **I've added recent dates also because, *in case of more than 1 day's difference Excel will not able to calculate the real time difference.***

My Formula calculates accurately rather than other.

Like if you use Formula **= INT((B2-A2)*24)** the answer will **2**, [when the Cell Format is General & if you covert it into HH:MM you get 00:00]

**Hope this help you, I've posted the solution after is been tested by me.**

Comment: Are you missing 55 minutes in the example? 23.55 to midnight is 55 minutes and then midnight to 01.35 is 1hr 35mins...

Comment: @Solar, No I did not. Originally the Start Time is 23:05 (24 Hrs Clock) if I simplify is 11 hrs & 5 Minutes and the End Time is 1:35.

Comment: So, if you use the 24h clock then 13 - 11 is 2.... 13.35 - 11 is 2.35 and take into account the 5 minutes is then 2hrs 30 mins

Comment: @Solar ,, Not again 23:05 means 11 Hrs & 5 Minutes (11:05 PM) at Night. And 01:35 is 1Hrs. 35Mnts is AM (earlier in Morning). Like Current Time is 14:30 (24 Hrs Clock) is 02:30 Pm (12 Hrs Clock), Just Check this ,http://www.onlineconversion.com/date_12-24_hour.htm

Comment: So, you are saying the 55 minutes worked prior to midnight does not count... I won't work for you : cheapskate...

Comment: @solar, I got where I was missing those precious 24 Hrs. Thanks!